# aria-hidden=“true” or aria-live=“assertive” is not working with foreach in lwc

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, nvda, lwc

I have a requirement where NVDA screen reader should read the error messages (dynamically displayed) on the lwc. I have an array with list of error messages and used to display them. However these messages are never read by NVDA Speech viewer. I tried adding aria-hidden="true", aria-live="assertive" and role="alert" along with aria-atomic="true" to tag but none of them working. Unable to find the issue, can anyone please help? Here is the code:

```
        <ul aria-live="assertive">
            <template for:each={Errors} for:item="err">
               <li class="slds-text-align--right" key={err}>{err}</li>
            </template>
        </ul>

        <ul role="alert" aria-atomic="true">
            <template for:each={Errors} for:item="err">
                <li class="slds-text-align--right" key={err}>{err}</li>
            </template>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the `aria-atomic` attribute on the element, it is used to set whether or not the screen reader should always present the live region as a whole, even if only part of the region changes.

Also, you need to add an `aria-relevant` attribute so that you can tell the screen reader that what type of change you did.

Possible values for the above attributes:

`aria-atomic="boolean"` **[default: false]**

`aria-relevant="additions/removals/text/all"` **[default:text]**

**Try this**

```
<ul aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" aria-relevant="additions">
    <template for:each={Errors} for:item="err">
        <li class="slds-text-align--right" key={err}>{err}</li>
    </template>
</ul>
```